# How do I manage storage for the images uploaded by users in my wallpaper website?

Tags: image, storage

I have 2 GB storage in my hosting plan. If the users upload high definition images, then this storage will run out very soon. What should I do for getting more storage space.

Solution to store user's uploaded images. Please help I have no idea what to do next.